# Delete object from ImmutableJS List based upon property value

Tags: javascript, node.js, immutable.js

What would be the simplest way to delete an object from a List based on a value of a property?

I'm looking for an equivalent of the $pull in MongoDB.

My List looks simple like this:

```
[{a: '1' , b: '1'},{a: '2' , b: '2'}]
```

And I'd like to remove from the array the object with property *a* set to '1'. In MongoDB, I'd do it like this:

```
Model.update({_id: getCorrectParentObj},{ $pull: {listIDeleteFrom: { a: '1' } } },(err, result)=>{});
```

How can I get the same result with ImmutableJS?

Comment: Plain js: `listIDeleteFrom = listIDeleteFrom.filter(function(item) { return item.a !== 1 });` (not sure about immutable, hence the comment)

Answer (score 23):

You could simply [`filter`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/filter) the immutable list:

```
var test = Immutable.List.of(Immutable.Map({a: '1'}), Immutable.Map({a: '2'}));
test = test.filter(function(item) { return item.get('a') !== '1' });
```

However, `filter` on non-empty `List` would result a different immutable list, thus you may want to check the occurrence of `{a: 1}` first:

```
if (test.some(function(item) { return item.get('a') === '1'; })) {
    test = test.filter(function(item) { return item.get('a') !== '1' });
}
```

Comment: Using [`filterNot`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/filterNot) instead of `filter` would arguably be slightly prettier.

Answer (score -7):

You don't need Immutable any anything specific for this, just use JavaScript array prototypes:

```
var test = [{a: '1' , b: '1'},{a: '2' , b: '2'}];

test.map(function(el,idx) { 
    return ( el.a == "1") ? idx : -1 
} ).filter(function(el) { 
    return el != -1 
}).forEach(function(el) { 
   test.splice(el,1) 
});
```

Results in:

```
[ { "a" : "2", "b" : "2" } ]
```

Or you could just get the value from `.filter()` with a reverse condition:

```
test.filter(function(el) {
    return el.a != 1;
});
```

Which does not actually affect the array "in place", but you could always "overwrite" with the result.

If the `test` variable is already an [Immutable](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) object then just convert it with `.toArray()` first, and re-cast back.

Answer (score -7):

maybe you can try [immutable-data](https://github.com/flutejs/immutable-data)

```
var immutableData = require("immutable-data")

var oldArray = [{a: '1' , b: '1'},{a: '2' , b: '2'}]

var data = immutableData(oldArray) 
var immutableArray = data.pick()

//modify immutableArray by ordinary javascript method
var i = 0
immutableArray.forEach(function(item,index){
  if (item.a === '1'){
    immutableArray.splice(index-i,1)
    i++
  }
})

var newArray = immutableArray.valueOf()

console.log(newArray)                    // [ { a: '2', b: '2' } ]
console.log(newArray[0]===oldArray[1])   // true
```

Comment: This is irrelevant; `immutable-data` does not have anything to do with Immutable.js.