# How to remove an object from an array in Immutable?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

Given a state like this:

```
state = {
  things: [
    { id: 'a1', name: 'thing 1' },
    { id: 'a2', name: 'thing 2' },
  ],
};
```

How can I create a new state where ID "a1" is removed? It's easy enough to push new items:

```
return state.set(state.get('things').push(newThing));
```

But I can't figure out how to search for and remove an object by its `id` property. I tried this:

```
return state.set('tracks',
  state.get('tracks').delete(
    state.get('tracks').findIndex(x => x.get('id') === 'a2')
  )
)
```

But it seems messy, plus it only works if the item is found, because if `findIndex` returns `-1`, that's a valid value for `delete`.

Comment: `state.update('things', things => things.filter(thing => thing.get('id') !== 'a2'));`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete object from ImmutableJS List based upon property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31466400/delete-object-from-immutablejs-list-based-upon-property-value)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
return state.set('things', state.get('things').filter(o => o.get('id') !== 'a1'));
```

Comment: So simple - I was apparently trying too hard to use Immutable's methods :) Thanks!

Comment: There's one caveat, this would always return a new immutable, even when the array has no matching elements. Depending on the size of the structure, this may be something worth knowing as it will effectively defeat any rendering optimizations done based on immutable state comparisons in React.

Comment: i am getting o.get is not a function... any help!!

Comment: I LOOOOOOOOVE this!!! way easier than looping through and splicing  , never again shall I do that.

Comment: I think this is wrong. Shouldn't it be setIn and getIn. ie. state.setIn('things', state.getIn('things').filter(o => o.get('id') !== 'a1'));

Comment: it worked for me but I needed o.id !== 'a1' and not o.get('id') !== 'a1'

Comment: This is the better answer when you don't have nested arrays. I came back here looking again for an answer but had to come up with one for deeply nested arrays but if you have something for that case as well, by all means.

Comment: 1) Why not use update instead of set? 2) Why would you loop through the entire array to remove one value?

Answer (score 15):

When you are using filter it iterates all cycle -> one effective way is finding index => slice and using splitter ...

```
const index = state.findIndex(data => data.id === action.id);

return [...state.slice(0, index), ...state.slice(index + 1)];
```

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, as you are "searching and then deleting"...

```
var itemIndex = this.state.get("tracks").findIndex(x => x.get('id') === 'a2');

return itemIndex > -1 ? this.state.deleteIn(["tracks", itemIndex]) : this.state;
```

This will ensure the state is not mutated when there are no changes.

Answer (score 1):

Found this thread while looking for a solution to a similar task.
Solved it with [update](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/update) method:

```
return state.update('things', (things) => things.filter((t) => t.id !== action.things.id))
```

any idea/comment which one is better/preferred?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that even without immutable.js with following function.

```
function arrayFilter(array, filter) {
  let ret = array
  let removed = 0
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    const passed = filter(array[index], index, array)
    if (!passed) {
      ret = [...ret.slice(0, index - removed), ...ret.slice(index - removed + 1)]
      removed++
    }
  }
  return ret
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## ImmutableJS working with nested arrays

Immutablejs is great but at the same time makes things more complicated in some edge cases, **particularly when working with nested arrays**.

Sometimes it is easier to take it back to JS in a general sense for this particular issue.

```
// 1. get a copy of the list into normal JavaScript
const myList = state.getIn(['root', 'someMap', 'myList']).toJS()

// 2. remove item in list using normal JavaScript and/or anything else
myList.splice(deleteIndex, 1)

// 3. return the new state based on mutated myList
return state
  .mergeDeep({ root: { someMap: { myList: undefined } }})
  .mergeDeep({ root: { someMap: { myList } }})
```

Unfortunately, step 3 is necessary to specifically set to `undefined` because if you simply set `myList` directly as an array value, ImmutableJS will do a comparison of values between the current list and only modify them creating strange behavior.

**The justification for this is to simplify the mental overhead.** I do not recommend doing this in a loop, rather manipulate the pure JS array in a loop if you must but should be prior to step 3.