# How delete from Immutable.List

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutable.js

Why deleteIn doesn't work for List? How to fix it so that the data remains immutable?

```
   import {OrderedMap, Record, List} from 'immutable';

   const ReducerState = Record({
        completedCount: new List([1,2,3])
    });

    const defaultState = new ReducerState();

    export default (tasksState = defaultState, action) => {
        const {type, payload} = action;
        switch (type) {
            case CHECK_TASK:
                return tasksState.deleteIn(['completedCount', payload.id]); // payload.id = 1
        };

    return tasksState;
};
```

Comment: Well it does work, check https://codesandbox.io/s/5xk643wypl

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete object from ImmutableJS List based upon property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31466400/delete-object-from-immutablejs-list-based-upon-property-value)

Answer (score 0):

I understood, it is necessary to delete on an index, instead of on the element

```
tasksState.deleteIn(['completedCount', tasksState.completedCount.indexOf(payload.id)])
```